# Msgbox to pop on First Working Day of February VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wanting to set a prompt on the first working day of February every year once. I'm not very good with this, and can only hard code it to a fixed date and it'll keep popping up when the user opens the file

```
Dim Dte As String
Dim wbmain as Workbook
Dim wsp As Worksheet

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Set wbmain = ThisWorkbook
Set wsp = wbmain.Worksheets("Path")

Dte = Format(Now(), "dd mmmm")

If Dte = "02 February" Then
    MsgBox "Please Change Paths"
    wsp.Activate
End Sub
```

Am wanting the "Please Change Paths" to only pop up once on the first working day of February every year, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will get your message box for each first working days of february not depending of the year :

```
Sub tst()

    Dte = Format(Now(), "dd mmmm yyyy")

    If Dte = CDate(Application.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month("19/02/2019"), 0), 1)) Then

                 MsgBox "Please Change Paths"
    End If

 End Sub
```

To test it try this

```
Sub tst()

Dte = Format("01/02/2019", "dd mmmm yyyy")

If Dte = CDate(Application.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month("19/02/2019"), 0), 1)) Then

             MsgBox "Please Change Paths"
    End If

End Sub
```

here "Now" will be the 01/02/2019 so the first working day of the month and you will get your message box !

**Note :** In your exemple "02/02/2019" is a week end day so not a working day

Comment: Thank you! However, this would still be hard coding the "first working day". Given that I input the date to be `01/02/2020` this pops up (but it's a Saturday) and doesn't pop when I input `03/02/2020` which is a Monday

Comment: @Valwrie the **only thing hard coded here is the month ("February")** As you asked for. The year will be the year of `Now()` Function so here 2019. next year it will be 2020. And there we calculate the first workday of the month "Frebruary" + This year (Now 2019). (Check the first code I gave you not the second which is a test exemple)
When you did **your test** you need to **replace** `Year(Now())` by a **2020** date for exemple `Year("19/07/2020")` and this will work ;)

Comment: you're right, my apologies, I'm a bit blind :X so what I did was test it with the first working day of Feb 2020 which is `("03/02/2020/")` and it doesn't pop up, but it works when I key in `("01/02/2020")` which is the first day of the month but not first working day, really confused as to how this all works

Comment: @Valwrie because you need to add the year here to `Dte = Format("03/02/2020", "dd mmmm yyyy")` I edited my aswer. your issue was here  **dd mmmm yyyy** and not **dd mmmm**

Comment: I've tried adding the year to that and changed the year as seen, but can't seem to test it :( `CDate(Application.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year(2020), Month("19/02/2019"), 0), 1))` debugging this gives me `2/1/1905` x.x

Comment: beacause you need `Year(2020)` don't work like that, copy and paste this : `CDate(Application.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year("20/05/2020"), Month("19/02/2019"), 0), 1))` @Valwrie and this will work `Year` select thet year of a **Date** !

Comment: @Valwrie Does it work with [Year()](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/year-function) function nicely setup ? Any feedbacks ?

Comment: yes it does! sorry it took awhile to get back! Didn't know that I had to set up a full date to get it to work! Thank you!